# Limits and continuous function book

Tags: limits

so I am looking for a very theoretical textbook which explain proofs regarding limits and continuous functions. Most textbooks I have found have very to no theory regarding them ( James Stewart Calculus)

Comment: Try Michael spivak's calculus! The explanation of 'limit' is so amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any book used for advanced calculus (by that, I mean a first graduate course in proofs). Try Buck or Apostol.